# Error: You've exceeded your current limit of 5 requests per second for query class

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

could someone correct this problem without having to change plan in cloudant?

Comment: No, you will have to change your plan.

Comment: Hi Frank, welcome to stackoverflow.  Please don't get disheartened by the down votes on your question,  the down votes are probably because the question does not meet the stackoverflow criteria for questions.  For more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the official Cloudant nodejs library, see the [retry plugin](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#the-retry-plugin) which handles 429 errors.

Note that 429 retry handling is probably only suitable for development environments or for the small fluctuations in demand that exceed your capacity.  Excessive use of 429 handling will result in a build up of 'back-pressure' in your application.

Comment: Thanks that helped us.